# Regex to Identify Fixed character alphanumeric word from text in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file from which i am trying to remove alpha-numeric word of seven characters.

```
Text1: " I have to remove the following word, **WORD123**, from the text given"
Text2: " I have to remove the following word, **WORD001**, the text given"
```

So far i tried `'\b[A-Za-z0-9]\b'` but it doesn't works.

Also , can we add a functionality that it picks only those words which is succeeded by "from"(not actual word, just an example).In the above example it should only pick `WORD123`, and not `WORD001` as the later one is not succeeded by `FROM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `re.sub` here, e.g.

```
inp = "I have to remove the following word, WORD123, FROM the text given"
out = re.sub(r'\s*\b[A-Za-z0-9]{7}\b[^\w]*(?=\bfrom)', '', inp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
I have to remove the following word,from the text given
```

Note that the above regex replacement does not match/affect the second sample input sentence you gave, since the 7 letter word is lacking the keyword `from` as the next word.

Comment: Thanks for the solution , it works. Can you also make a change to make "From" as case in-sensitive ?

Comment: @user10136853 Just add a flag to the `re.sub` call to run it in case insensitive mode, q.v. my updated answer above.